# Are Float and Double instances of Fractional?

Tags: haskell

If I enter ":i Double" or ":i Float" in ghci, it says that Double and Float are instances of Fractional. But in the Haskell docs it says that they aren't. So are they or not?
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Fractional

Comment: They are -- `:i` is reliable, they are listed as instances of `Floating` (which has `Fractional` as superclass), and if you go to the [source code for `Double`'s `Floating` instance](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Float.html#line-466) you will find the `Fractional` one a few lines above. This does look like a  documentation/Haddock bug of some sort, though -- the instances should have been listed there.

Comment: (This seems to be a known Haddock bug -- cf. [Haddock issue #372](https://github.com/haskell/haddock/issues/372).)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- `Double` and `Float` are a part of `RealFloat`,

  - which extends `RealFrac` and `Floating`;

    - both of which extend `Fractional`.